# How to replace goto command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am only starting out programming and currently making a text game. I know there is no goto command in python and after doing some research I understood that I have to use loops to replace that command but it just isn't doing what i was hoping it would do. Here's my code:

```
print('Welcome to my bad game!')
print('Please, press Enter to continue.')
variable=input()
if variable == '':
    print('You are in a dark forest. You can only choose one item. Press 1 for a flashlight and press 2 for an axe.')
while True:
    item=input()
    if item=='2':
        print('Bad choice, you lost the game.')
        quit()
    if item=='1':
        print('Good choise, now you can actually see something.')
```

So my problem with this is that if the player chooses the 'wrong' item the program just kills itself but I would want it to jump back to the beginning. I actually don't know if this is even possible but better ask than just wonder.

Comment: instead of while True, you would loop on a condition, like while playing: and instead of quit(), it could be playing = False

Comment: From what line would you execute again?

Comment: I recommend seeking out a basic tutorial (the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) is quite good). Whenever you have doubts as to whether something is possible, browse through the topic listing - you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to the beginning to the loop, just leave out the call to `quit`.  If you mean to the beginning of the *program*, then you'll need a loop around that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of quit you could use 'continue' to loop back to your while. But it's not clear from this example what you want the while to do.